# Можно ли на CSS присвоить элементу width соседнего элемента (не родительского)?

Tags: css

На JS велосипедов изобретать не хочу.

Comment: Можно. Задать и там и там одно значение для width, почему нет. И соседний слева/справа? И приведите пример разметки.

Comment: @edem Задать и там и там одно значение для width нельзя, т.к. я его не знаю. Ширина элемента определяется его содержимым. Я так понимаю нельзя это сделать на CSS.

Comment: Да Вы уточните все подробности в самом вопросе, а там посмотрим. Соседний элемент у которого будем брать ширину находиться слева или справа от нужного элемента?

Comment: `CSS` не имеет доступа к применённым параметрам. Раз ширина неизвестна и нужна та, что применена, только `JS`, там легко.

Comment: @Other Да, там легко конструировать велосипеды :D

Comment: Это не велосипед. Да и к тому же велосипед велосипеду — рознь: кто сказал, что ваша логика должна совпадать с чьей-то другой? А если она совпадает в какой-то мере и вы начинаете её переписывать, то это уже велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться подобным подходом:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div contenteditable>Нажмите для редактирования</div>
  <div>Соседний блок</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Ещё блок с каким-то содержимым.</div>
  <div>Другой соседний блок</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этого селектор +

```
.class1 + .class2 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Задать и там и там одно значение для width нельзя, т.к. я его не знаю. Ширина элемента определяется его содержимым. Так что "+" не решение.